# PHP $_POST[][] two dimensional array to json_encode adding extra single quotes

Tags: php, mysql, json, post

The problem is that I am naming my form elements like the following (Highlighted):

[image]

There are the collection of arrays in my form. Now I want to save these arrays in MySql database table which has json dataType (I am using MySQL v-8 with PHPDO). For this purpose I have used the following function to convert my $_POST array to json array:

```
  $case = json_encode($_POST['case']);
```

It working fine and saving record in my table's columns but here is the problem that it stores the keys with the following manners:

[image]

In the above snapshot you may see that each **key** has been enclosed by **double quotes** and then with **single quotes**.

I need to save the same record with json column but without **single quotation** after **double quotes**.

What am I doing wrong? My Php code for the above to convert from $_POST['case'] array to json array is as follow:

```
    ......
    $case = json_encode($_POST['case']);
    $ret = json_encode($_POST['ret']);
    $discussion = $_POST['discussion'];
    $next_appointment_date = $_POST['next_appointment_date'];
    $remarks = isset($_POST['remarks']) && !empty($_POST['remarks']) ? trim($_POST['remarks']):'';
    $signature = isset($_POST['signature']) && !empty($_POST['signature']) ? trim($_POST['signature']):'';
    //search the same case details before saving...
    $sql_search = "SELECT * FROM case_information 
                   WHERE case_info->>'$.first_party' = :first_party 
                        AND case_info->>'$.second_party' = :second_party 
                        AND case_info->>'$.case_nature' = :case_nature
                        AND case_info->>'$.received_date' = :received_date";
    $parem_search = array(':first_party'=>$_POST['case']["'first_party'"],
                          ':second_party'=>$_POST['case']["'second_party'"],
                          ':case_nature'=>$_POST['case']["'case_nature'"],
                          ':received_date'=>$_POST['case']["'received_date'"]);
        if($db->dbQuery($sql_search,$parem_search)){
            echo('3');
        }else{
            //insert new record
            $sql_insert = "INSERT INTO case_information (
                case_info,
                instituted_by,
                returned_to,
                discussion,
                remarks,
                next_date_apt,
                person_signature,
                entry_made_on
              )
              VALUES
                (
                :case_info,
                :instituted_by,
                :returned_to,
                :discussion,
                :remarks,
                :next_date_apt,
                :person_signature,
                :entry_made_on  
                )";
            $param = array(
                        ':case_info'=>$case,
                        ':instituted_by'=>$ins,
                        ':returned_to'=>$ret,
                        ':discussion'=>$discussion,
                        ':remarks'=>$remarks,
                        ':next_date_apt'=>$next_appointment_date,
                        ':person_signature'=>$signature,
                        ':entry_made_on'=>date('Y-m-d')
                        );
                //echo($sql_insert);
                if($db->dbQuery($sql_insert,$param)){
                        echo('4');
                }else{
                         .
                         .
```

Comment: (Please do not declare your questions as definitively not a duplicate. Readers need you to be open to the possibility that you missed one, and if one is suggested, there is an expectation that you will seriously consider it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use the single quotes in your HTML form. Just array[fieldname] is enough. Like this:

```
<input type="text" name="case[first_party]" id="first_party" />
```